# Numerical calculation of spherical photon orbits near Kerr black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, computational-physics, differential-equations

I'm using RK4 method for solving differential equation

$$\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}=\pm(2-2r)\frac{\sqrt{Q-\left(\frac{\Phi^2}{\sin^2\theta}-1\right)\cos^2}\theta}{2r+\left(r^2+\cos^2\theta-2r\right)\frac{\Phi} {\sin^2\theta}}\qquad \theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Taking inspiration mostly from this article: [Spherical Photon Orbits around a Kerr Black Hole](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1026286607562.pdf) ( [link to version on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.04022) ).

The equation above regards photon movement in $\theta$ and $\phi$ direction around a rotating black hole with angular momentum $$a=M$$
This qualitative graph shows values of $\Phi$ and $Q$ with respect to the radius of the spherical orbit. For this situatuion $r_1=M$ and $r_2=4M$
[image]

I am able to calculate trajectories for every $r$ from the interval $(r_1,r_3)$, by that I mean the obtained orbits look just like the ones in the mentioned article. However if I use $r$ from the interval $(r_3,r_2)$ I get very weird, obviously wrong, results. Here is the obtained numerical solution for $r=1+\sqrt3$ for example. The axes are X,Y and Z

[image]

Does anyone know what might be causing these kinks? I tried making the step in RK4 smaller, but that didn't help. I also tried using a substitution $u=\cos\theta$, but that produced same results.

Comment: What's on the axes in the second plot?

Comment: X,Y,Z, it's just a 3D space

Comment: I think you may need to provide a bit more details so that we may see what the issue is. Are you setting the values of $\Phi$ and $Q$ properly? What happens at $\Phi=0?$

Comment: Yeah $\Phi$ and $Q$ are definitelly calculated properly. When I set $\Phi$ I get expected trajectory, just like the one in Teo's paper. However if I go any lower than 0, the kinks starts to happen